# React SPA with asp.net-core Does Not Update (caches) Between Deployments

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have developed a React SPA based upon ASP, Identity Server, and dotnet core 3.1 (deployed via Docker/Kubernetes). I have noticed that the assets are being cached between deployments, causing users to not see an updated version of the app. Looking at the headers returned by any of the files (index, css, js, etc.) I see a modification date of yesterday:

```
date: Sat, 10 Oct 20202
```

If I force-refresh the page, the new version appears. I see the new modification dates, as well as a new `etag` in the response headers. But if I then normal refresh again, it reverts to the old version.

I have tried adding cache headers, which does fix the problem going forward, but does not seem like the right approach:

```
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = false,
        OnPrepareResponse = (ctx) => {
          ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,max-age=" + 60;
        }
      });
```

[...routing...]

```
      app.UseSpa(spa => {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "App";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions() {
          OnPrepareResponse = (ctx) => {
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,max-age=" + 60;
          }
        };

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
          spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
        }
      });
```

Note that I am using a service worker, but again, it was generated by the Visual Studio / dotnet templates.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this. Just faced the same issue.